# Comparing Security: Custom Login Page vs. AWS Hosted Callback with Cognito User Pools in React Applications

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, websecurity

I am in the process of transitioning my monolithic ASPX WebForms application to a modern architecture utilizing a React frontend and a C# REST API backend. A particular area of inquiry for me concerns the mechanisms of authentication and authorization within this new setup.

To facilitate user management, I have established User Pools in the AWS Cognito console. Rather than adopting callback-based routing, I am contemplating the development of bespoke login and signup pages . This approach, however, raises concerns regarding the security implications of crafting a custom authentication solution as opposed to leveraging the AWS Hosted UI.

Could you provide insight into which option would offer superior security in the long term?